# Ecto Migrations specify collation

Tags: elixir, ecto

How do I specify the column [collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/collation.html) while using *add* in Ecto Migrations? I am using Postgres.

I saw an option of using custom types like specifying :"varchar(120)", but :"varchar(120) collate "C"" does not work due to the necessary quotes.

I know I can fallback to raw sql, but would prefer to leverage *add*.